# Chrome browser doesn't open in kiosk mode using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium WebDriver with chrome browser and for whatever reason, it doesn't open in kiosk mode. This used to work, not sure why it stopped.

**This is my code:**

```
        private IWebDriver GetChromeDriver(BrowserConfigurationOptions browserConfigOptions)
    {
        var options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.AddArguments("disable-infobars");
        options.AddUserProfilePreference("credentials_enable_service", false);
        if (browserConfigOptions.KioskModeForChrome)
            options.AddArgument("--kiosk"); //options.AddArgument("--enable-kiosk-mode");
        LogChromeOptions(options);

        return new ChromeDriver(options);
    }
```

**This is my environment:**

- Chrome 66
- Selenium WebDriver v 3.11.2
- Chromedriver version 2.38.0.1 from this [Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver/)

I've tried passing in --kiosk and --enable-kiosk-mode with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After seeing that everyone had this working except me, I started digging further. After digging into the code I found

**Driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();**

being called after initialization of the driver. After removing this line of code, I was able to open Chrome in kiosk mode with the solution above.

Answer (score 2):

To initialize the *Chrome Browser* in **Kiosk Mode** you need to pass the following argument through an instance of *ChromeOptions* class:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--kiosk");
return new ChromeDriver(options);
```

**Note A** : As per *Java Doc*, it is arguments are passed as **`addArguments()`**

**Note B** : As per [Peter Beverloo](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)

- **`--kiosk`**:

  ```
  Enables kiosk mode. Please note this is not Chrome OS kiosk mode.
  ```
- Sample Code(Java):

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
  ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
  options.addArguments("--kiosk");
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
  driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: Chrome_Kiosk_Mode]

Comment: @demouser123 Yup, `options.addArguments("--kiosk");` still works at my end. Browser snapshot attached.

Answer (score 0):

Config issue as Chrome 66 is supported by Chromedriver 2.38 and you're using 2.18

Please update from below.

http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Comment: Sorry about that, instead of 2.38, I wrote 2.18. My version is 2.38. I wish this solution was as easy as that :(